# How to add results of a SELECT to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL select statement which is comparing two tables. I am getting the values where the rows are the same. Now I have got this in the procedure I need to add these into a new table (`coftReconciliationMatches`). The table has all the same columns but one additional one '`MatchOrNoMatch`'. I need to pass through the values of the row that are matched and also need to pass through '`Match`' to the column '`MatchOrNoMatch`'

This is the current part of the SQL script I have;

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.coftReconciliationFileInfo AS a 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM dbo.coftPreReconciliationInfo AS b 
                WHERE a.Rec_PK = b.Rec_PK 
                  AND a.ExtRef1 = b.ExtRef1 
                  AND a.SedolRef = b.SedolRef 
                  AND a.ValLatest = b.ValLatest 
                  AND a.Totunits = b.Totunits 
                  AND a.FundsOrCash = b.FundsOrCash )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing a lot of columns, the SELECT INTERSECT and SELECT EXCEPT commands can save you a lot of effort:

```
INSERT dbo.coftReconcilliationMatches
   (Rec_PK, ExtRef1, SedolRef, ValLatest, Totunits, FundsOrCash, MatchOrNoMatch)
 select Rec_PK, ExtRef1, SedolRef, ValLatest, Totunits, FundsOrCash, 'Match'
  from dbo.coftReconciliationFileInfo
 intersect select Rec_PK, ExtRef1, SedolRef, ValLatest, Totunits, FundsOrCash, 'Match'
  from dbo.coftPreReconciliationFileInfo
```

(Check for typos!)

If you are creating the table on the fly (something I wouldn't recommend doing), you'd use `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! is there a way of doing this method but if they do not match?

Comment: `SELECT...EXCEPT...` gets everything in the first set that is not, column for column, in the second set.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([col1], [col2]) SELECT colx, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select Into` for this. See here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO <your table> (<list of columns>)
SELECT <list of columns from select>, '<the additional column>' FROM dbo.coftReconciliationFileInfo AS a 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.coftPreReconciliationInfo AS b 
WHERE a.Rec_PK = b.Rec_PK AND a.ExtRef1 = b.ExtRef1 AND a.SedolRef = b.SedolRef AND     a.ValLatest = b.ValLatest AND a.Totunits = b.Totunits AND a.FundsOrCash = b.FundsOrCash )
```

also see http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to do:

```
INSERT INTO Table (column1, column2..)
(SELECT column1, column2 .... 
  FROM dbo.coftReconciliationFileInfo AS a 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM dbo.coftPreReconciliationInfo AS b 
                WHERE a.Rec_PK = b.Rec_PK 
                  AND a.ExtRef1 = b.ExtRef1 
                  AND a.SedolRef = b.SedolRef 
                  AND a.ValLatest = b.ValLatest 
                  AND a.Totunits = b.Totunits 
                  AND a.FundsOrCash = b.FundsOrCash ))
```